# Update multiple rows with multiple condtions "each row with a different condition"

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

I want to make an update sql statement that could update multiple rows with multiple conditions each row depend on different condition like this one:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET row1_field1=newValue1, Row1_field2=newValue2 
WHERE row1_condition1=condition1
  AND SET row2_field1=newValue1, row2_field2=newValue2 WHERE row2_condition1=condition1
  AND SET row3_field1=newValue1, row3_field2=newValue2 WHERE row3_condition1=condition1
```

Comment: use multiple queries, it's easier and more understandable

Answer (score 1):

For that you should use [CASE UPDATE](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=case%20update%20mysql&rlz=1C1CHMO_en-GBIN559IN559&oq=case%20update%20&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.6084j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=case%20update%20sql) . There are plenty of examples avail online.

eg:

```
update table set
    columnx = (case when condition then new_valuex else columnx end),
    columny = (case when condition then new_valuey else columny end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
UPDATE tableName
SET row1_field1=case when row1_condition1=condition1 then newValue1 end, 
Row1_field2=case when row1_condition1=condition1 then newValue2 end,
row2_field1=case when row2_condition1=condition1 then newValue1 end , 
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this dynamically this easy. you have to put a hardcoded value in the `<conditionRow..>` in the WHEN clause:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET field1 = CASE WHEN condition = <conditionRow1_field1> THEN newValue1 
                  WHEN condition = <conditionRow2_field1> THEN newValue2 
                  ...
             ELSE field1 END,
    field1 = CASE WHEN condition = <conditionRow1_field2> THEN newValueRow1_field2 
                  WHEN condition = <conditionRow2_field1> THEN newValueRow2_field2 
                  ...
             ELSE field2 END
```